# How to clear the address in a message?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I can add a reply-to address to a message using this code:

```
 msgReplyTo= {'ReplyTo':[{'EmailAddress': 
 {'Address': sA,'Name': sN }}]};
 msgReplyTo = JSON.stringify(msgReplyTo); 

 $.ajax({
 url: MessageUrl,
 type : 'PATCH',
 headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
 accessToken, 'Content-Type':   
'application/json' },
 data : msgReplyTo
 }).success(function (response) 
 {  
 ...
```

Now I want to clear the Reply-to address. What syntax should I use?

Thanks,
Victor Ivanidze

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I assume you want to update the message and clear the replay to address.

Based on my test, we can set the replay to like this：

`"replyTo":[

```
]`
```

and using the update endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}` to clear the replay-to address

Comment: Hello kikang, unfortunately that doesn't work at all (I've just tried to use your syntax at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

Comment: Disregard my previous comment - it works for a message in Drafts folder. Please confirm that there is no way to clear the editable message property using endpoint 
     https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/{id}

Comment: Could you please provide the endpoint that you want to use? Microsoft Graph API? Outlook Office Rest API?